# how to fix System.ArgumentException: 'Option 'checkparameters' not supported.'

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am creating a crystal report to display the records from MySQL database. I am unsure whats going wrong here.

Please can you help?

```
public void tbl_invoice_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string mycon1 = ("...");
    MySqlConnection scon1 = new MySqlConnection(mycon1);
    MySqlCommand cmdDataBase1 = new MySqlCommand();
    MySqlDataAdapter sda1 = new MySqlDataAdapter("select max(ref_no) from vtech.estimate where reg_no = '" + txt_reg_no.Text + "'", mycon1);
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    sda1.Fill(dt1);
    lbl_estimate_reference.Text = dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString();

    generate_report();
}

public void generate_report() {
    // Create a Dataset and using DataAdapter to fill it 
    invoice_report report;
    report = new invoice_report();
    dataset_invoice_print reportdataset = new dataset_invoice_print();
    dataset_invoice_printTableAdapters.customer_infoTableAdapter
    adapter_customer_info = new dataset_invoice_printTableAdapters.customer_infoTableAdapter();
    adapter_customer_info.Fill(reportdataset.customer_info);
    report.SetDataSource(reportdataset)
    invoice_viewer.ReportSource = report;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key information to solve your problem is in the connection string, which you've omitted from your question:

```
string mycon1 = ("...");
```

I'm going to guess you're using [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) and that your connection string contains `CheckParameters=X` (`True` or `False`, it doesn't really matter).

As per https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/#unsupported-options, `CheckParameters` isn't supported in the connection string because:

> MySqlConnector always checks stored procedure parameters efficiently; there’s no need to disable this.

Remove `CheckParameters=True;` (or `CheckParameters=False;`) from your connection string and you should avoid this exception.